# React-native WebView doesn't keep user logged in iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, webview

I've built a simple application that loads a page using [Webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#:%7E:text=React%20Native%20WebView%20is%20a%20modern%2C%20well-supported%2C%20and,their%20free%20time%20and%20their%20company%20work%20time.) and, even though I've allowed cookies and cache, once the app is closed, the user is logged out from the website. PS.: This only happens in iOS devices, not in Android.

```
import React from 'react';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const WebViewPage = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'my-url' }}
      onError={() => navigate('Error')}
      thirdPartyCookiesEnabled
      allowFileAccess
      cacheEnabled
      sharedCookiesEnabled
    />
  );
};

export default WebViewPage;
```

I've found solutions for Flutter applications, but not for React-native.